# How can I have two rows of uneven, centered elements with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

This is the layout I am trying to create:

[image]

It is a grid of boxes:

- The max amount of elements per box must be configurable (4, in this case, but should be able to be different amounts).
- if the last row is not complete and has "orphans", the elements must remain centered, but with the same width as the other boxes.
- The grid must use the whole width of its container. This means, no space surrounding the boxes outside, when the row is full.
- **Preferably** must exist a way to set the gap between boxes

I thought the best tool for this would be flexbox but I have encountered the following problems:

My approach was this:

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width: 22%;
  height: 200px;
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

which yields this result:

[image]

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/dbugger/pen/VwLwedr?editors=0100)

Here there are several problems:

1. The last row is not centered.
2. I cannot set a fixed margin between boxes. I would like also that this margin is always the same, no matter how many elements a row can fit.
3. Minor inconvenience really, but the way to set the amount of max elements per row is flaky. I would have to make an operation dividing 100 / max, which may result in weird results (100 / 3 = 33.333333...).

How could I get a better result?

**UPDATE**

A requirement that I forgot to add:

- The grid must use the whole width of its container. This means, no space surrounding the boxes outside, when the row is full.

Comment: justify-content:center; is what you need ( commented earlier in your other question) , element can receive margin not to stick to each others

Comment: Essentially, your detailed requirements **cannot** be met with flexbox. You can get *most* of the way but the restrictions you add mean that you can't get *all* the way there.

Comment: @Paulie_D please, comment my answer. Had I got *all the way there*, or I missed something by your view. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096118/7546986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE scale illustrating**

- We use `css` `variables`, such as `--margin-right-value`, `--row-elements-number`
- We use classes form `.boxes2` to `.boxes20` to define different behavior of rows with different element numbers.
- We wrap our `.boxes<number>` classes to simplify `css`, we match classes starting with *`boxes`* inside wrapper, optionaly, can maintain without wrapper.
- Of course `margin-top` (can be used as variable as well if needed) and `--margin-right-value` can be specified within every `.boxes<number>` class.

Once written, can use classes after where you want.

Look into the snippet. Or https://jsfiddle.net/beluginni/kb8L71c3/

```css
.wrapper [class*="boxes"] {
  margin-bottom: 30px; /* to separate visualy*/
}

:root {
  --margin-right-value: 10px; /* margin between elements in row, can be specified within each of boxes<n> classes */
}

.boxes2 { --row-elements-number: 2; }
.boxes3 { --row-elements-number: 3; }
.boxes4 { --row-elements-number: 4; }
.boxes5 { --row-elements-number: 5; }
.boxes6 { --row-elements-number: 6; }
.boxes7 { --row-elements-number: 7; }
.boxes8 { --row-elements-number: 8; }
.boxes9 { --row-elements-number: 9; }
.boxes10 { --row-elements-number: 10; }
.boxes11 { --row-elements-number: 11; }
.boxes12 { --row-elements-number: 12; }
.boxes13 { --row-elements-number: 13; }
.boxes14 { --row-elements-number: 14; }
.boxes15 { --row-elements-number: 15; }
.boxes16 { --row-elements-number: 16; }
.boxes17 { --row-elements-number: 17; }
.boxes18 { --row-elements-number: 18; }
.boxes19 { --row-elements-number: 19; }
.boxes20 { --row-elements-number: 20; }


.wrapper [class*="boxes"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: dotted red 1px;
}


/*width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (<row_el_number> - 1))) / <row_el_number>)*/
.box {
  width: calc((100% - (var(--margin-right-value) * (var(--row-elements-number) - 1))) / var(--row-elements-number));
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.boxes2 .box:nth-child(n+3),
.boxes3 .box:nth-child(n+4),
.boxes4 .box:nth-child(n+5),
.boxes5 .box:nth-child(n+6),
.boxes6 .box:nth-child(n+7),
.boxes7 .box:nth-child(n+8),
.boxes8 .box:nth-child(n+9),
.boxes9 .box:nth-child(n+10),
.boxes10 .box:nth-child(n+11),
.boxes11 .box:nth-child(n+12),
.boxes12 .box:nth-child(n+13),
.boxes13 .box:nth-child(n+14),
.boxes14 .box:nth-child(n+15),
.boxes15 .box:nth-child(n+16),
.boxes16 .box:nth-child(n+17),
.boxes17 .box:nth-child(n+18),
.boxes18 .box:nth-child(n+19),
.boxes19 .box:nth-child(n+20),
.boxes20 .box:nth-child(n+21) {
  margin-top: 4%; /* margin between rows, can be represented as var and specified within each of boxes<n> classes */
}

.boxes2 .box:not(:nth-child(2n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes3 .box:not(:nth-child(3n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes4 .box:not(:nth-child(4n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes5 .box:not(:nth-child(5n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes6 .box:not(:nth-child(6n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes7 .box:not(:nth-child(7n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes8 .box:not(:nth-child(8n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes9 .box:not(:nth-child(9n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes10 .box:not(:nth-child(10n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes11 .box:not(:nth-child(11n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes12 .box:not(:nth-child(12n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes13 .box:not(:nth-child(13n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes14 .box:not(:nth-child(14n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes15 .box:not(:nth-child(15n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes16 .box:not(:nth-child(16n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes17 .box:not(:nth-child(17n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes18 .box:not(:nth-child(18n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes19 .box:not(:nth-child(19n)):not(:last-child),
.boxes20 .box:not(:nth-child(20n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: var(--margin-right-value);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxes2">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes4">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes5">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes6">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes7">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes8">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes9">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes10">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes11">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes12">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes13">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes14">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes15">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes16">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes17">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes18">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes19">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxes20">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFieddle to play with different values](https://jsfiddle.net/w9osfkj1/)

**UPDATE better margin and .box width definition**

Formulas to calculate `.box` `width` and `margin` between them:

**If margin is known:** `width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (<row_elements_number> - 1))) / <row_elements_number>)`.

- **For 4** in a row `.box` `width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (4 - 1))) / 4)`
- **For 3** in a row `.box` `width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (3 - 1))) / 3)`
- **For 5** in a row `.box` `width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (5 - 1))) / 5)`

**If .box width is known:** `margin-rigth: calc((100% - <.box_width_value> * <row_elements_number>) / (<row_elements_number> - 1))`.

- **For 4** in a row `margin-rigth: calc((100% - <.box_width_value> * 4) / (4 - 1))`
- **For 3** in a row `margin-rigth: calc((100% - <.box_width_value> * 3) / (3 - 1))`
- **For 5** in a row `margin-rigth: calc((100% - <.box_width_value> * 5) / (5 - 1))`

`css` is simple

```
.box:not(:nth-child(<row-elements-number>n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: <desired value>;
}
```

**THE MAIN IDEA**

is to make `justify-content: center;` and add `margins` to every child **except** `:nth-child(<row-elements-number>n)):not(:last-child)`. In our case every `4th` and `last` has no margin value.

Lets take `margin-rigth: 4%` => *box-width* is `calc((100% - (4% * (4 - 1))) / 4)`

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dotted black 1px; /* to see edges */
}

/*width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (4 - 1))) / 4)*/
.box {
  width: calc((100% - (4% * (4 - 1))) / 4);
  height: 100px; /* changed */
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.box:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: 4%; /*added*/
}

.box:not(:nth-child(4n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE to illustrate adjustments**

To control `margin` after last row replaced `margin-bottom: value;` in `box` class with

```
.box:nth-child(n + (<row_elements_number> + 1)) {
  margin-top: <desired_value>;
}
```

**Case for 3 in a row**

Lets take `margin-right: 1%` => `.box` `width:calc((100% - (1% * (3 - 1))) / 3)`

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dotted black 1px; /* to see edges */
}

/*width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (3 - 1))) / 3)*/
.box {
  width: calc((100% - (1% * (3 - 1))) / 3);
  height: 100px; /* changed */
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.box:nth-child(n+4) {
  margin-top: 1%; /*added*/
}

.box:not(:nth-child(3n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Case for 5 in a row**

Lets take `margin-right: 5%` => `.box` `width: calc((100% - (5% * (5 - 1))) / 5)`

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dotted black 1px; /* to see edges */
}

/* width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (5 - 1))) / 5) */
.box {
  width: calc((100% - (5% * (5 - 1))) / 5);
  height: 100px; /* changed */
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.box:nth-child(n+6) {
  margin-top: 5%; /*added*/
}

.box:not(:nth-child(5n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Case for 4 in a row and small fixed gaps (*margin-value* is 4px)**

=> `.box` `width:calc((100% - (4px * (4 - 1))) / 4)`

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dotted black 1px; /* to see edges */
}

/* width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (4 - 1))) / 4) */
.box {
  width: calc((100% - (4px * (4 - 1))) / 4);
  height: 100px; /* changed */
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.box:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: 4px; /*added*/
}

.box:not(:nth-child(4n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Case for 4 in a row and big fixed gaps (*margin-value* is 80px)**

=> `.box` `width:calc((100% - (80px * (4 - 1))) / 4)`

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dotted black 1px; /* to see edges */
}

/* width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (4 - 1))) / 4) */
.box {
  width: calc((100% - (80px * (4 - 1))) / 4);
  height: 100px; /* changed */
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.box:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: 80px; /*added*/
}

.box:not(:nth-child(4n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Case for 4 in a row and fixed boxes width (60px)**

=> `margin-right: calc((100% - 60px * 4) / (4 - 1))`.

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dotted black 1px; /* to see edges */
}

/* margin-rigth: calc((100% - <.box_width_value> * 4) / (4 - 1)) */
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px; /* changed */
  /* pure decoration... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;
}

.box:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: calc((100% - 60px * 4) / (4 - 1)); /*added*/
}

.box:not(:nth-child(4n)):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: calc(33.33% - 80px);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works, one of the conditions was `The max amount of elements per box must be configurable (4, in this case, but should be able to be different amounts).` This wont work if I want to have 3 or 5 per row.

Comment: Also you are forcing the gap between boxes. There is no chance to adjust it

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent maybe I don't understand what do you mean, that it can't be adjusted. Made update, how I see it. Please look and say, what do you think.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent updated answer ones more. Made margins `css` definition more flexible and easy.

Comment: When I try to replicate it for other than 4, I dont get the same results

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent but in snippets you see that all working? Could you make some codepen or jsfiddle where it doesn't work for you? Just in case point that after moving from 4 to for example 5, you have to change only 2 places: `.box {
  width: calc((100% - (<margin_value> * (4 - 1))) / 4);}` 4 is changing on 5 and `.box:nth-child(n + 5) {margin-top: <desired_value>;}` 5 is changing to 6

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent and of cousre the 3rd place to chage is `.box:not(:nth-child(<row-elements-number>n)):not(:last-child) {margin-right: <desired value>;}`

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent I marked what 3 places is needed to be changed in jsfield, feel free to try and please tell if everything is ok. It seems all working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/w9osfkj1/

Comment: I see. Now it works. It has just a *small* problem. I have to write as many rules as "columns per row" I want to support. If I want to support between 2 and 20, I would have to write all the rules 19 times. The solution does not scale too well. Still, I'm going to upvote your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent upddated my answer. It is scalable. Look description at the top of answer. Look the snippet to check or JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rvz5kL80/

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent if you have more questions, please ask. IMHO with last update all your requirements are fullfiled and scalable sulution is provided.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do using CSS variables to simplify the way to scale this application. But CSS variables are not really a solution for parameters that come actually from the backend. In any case, I am going to accept it, for being close enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add the `justify-content` property to center the boxes and `align-content` should be `space-around`.

```
.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: space-around;
}
```

For the box styles, you'll need a margin around them to space them out.

Here's a codepen of the working version: https://codepen.io/usmanity/pen/zYGYrgZ?editors=0100

Comment: The problem here is that then, the grid would not use the complete width of its container

Answer (score 1):

[Check here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBM0OQ13D8BB)

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  /*edited*/
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 23%;
  height: 13rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  background: green;

  /*edited*/
  margin: 1%; /* or .5rem*/
  border-radius: .2rem;
```

[image]

**Thank you**

Comment: It is sadly not using the whole width of the container

Comment: Try using ```width: 100vw``` on boxes

Comment: It wont work. It wont stretch the box to use the whole width

Comment: You are confusing me. Ok...ok.. ```boxes```  have 100% of width and make each```box``` of 23% and give margin 1% this will be total 100% or if want more box width then do 24% and margin .5%.

Comment: Please don't use images of code. Also consider using [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for your example, it provides and interactive example in your answer, so we don't have to go off site to get the whole picture.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try this - 
    <ul class="boxes">
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
      </ul>

    ul.boxes {
      margin: 0 -10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    ul li.box {
      width: calc(100%/4 - 20px);
      background-color: green;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 0 10px 20px;
    }
```